# How Can I deploy Apps in app service with private GitHub repository using REST API or ARM templates?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager, azure-management-api, azure-rest-api

The following is the ARM template I am using to create a app service and use a private GitHub repo to deploy applications with deployment for application fails.

```
{
               "properties": {
               "mode": "Incremental",
               "template":{
                "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.1",
                "parameters": {
                    "siteName": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "defaultValue": "[concat(\'WebApp-\', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
                        "metadata": {
                            "description": "The name of you Web Site."
                        }
                    },
                    "location": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
                        "metadata": {
                            "description": "Location for all resources."
                        }
                    },
                    "sku": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "allowedValues": [
                            "F1",
                            "D1",
                            "B1",
                            "B2",
                            "B3",
                            "S1",
                            "S2",
                            "S3",
                            "P1",
                            "P2",
                            "P3",
                            "P4"
                        ],
                        "defaultValue": "F1",
                        "metadata": {
                            "description": "The pricing tier for the hosting plan."
                        }
                    },
                    "workerSize": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "allowedValues": [
                            "0",
                            "1",
                            "2"
                        ],
                        "defaultValue": "0",
                        "metadata": {
                            "description": "The instance size of the hosting plan (small, medium, or large)."
                        }
                    },
                    "repoURL": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "defaultValue": "https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-web-html-get-started.git",
                        "metadata": {
                            "description": "The URL for the GitHub repository that contains the project to deploy."
                        }
                    },
                    "branch": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "defaultValue": "master",
                        "metadata": {
                            "description": "The branch of the GitHub repository to use."
                        }
                    }
                },
                "variables": {
                    "hostingPlanName": "jhyhfgljgljuhg-Plan"
                },
                "resources": [
                    {
                        "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
                        "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
                        "name": "[variables(\'hostingPlanName\')]",
                        "location": "[parameters(\'location\')]",
                        "sku": {
                            "name": "[parameters(\'sku\')]",
                            "capacity": "[parameters(\'workerSize\')]"
                        },
                        "properties": {
                            "name": "[variables(\'hostingPlanName\')]"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
                        "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
                        "name": "[parameters(\'siteName\')]",
                        "location": "[parameters(\'location\')]",
                        "identity": {
                            "type": "SystemAssigned"
                      },
                        "dependsOn": [
                            "[resourceId(\'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms\', variables(\'hostingPlanName\'))]"
                        ],
                        "properties": {
                            "serverFarmId": "[variables(\'hostingPlanName\')]"
                        },
                        "resources": [
                            {
                                "type": "sourcecontrols",
                                "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
                                "name": "web",
                                "location": "[parameters(\'location\')]",
                                "dependsOn": [
                                    "[resourceId(\'Microsoft.Web/sites\', parameters(\'siteName\'))]"
                                ],
                                "properties": {
                                    "repoUrl": "[parameters(\'repoURL\')]",
                                    "branch": "[parameters(\'branch\')]",
                                    "isManualIntegration": true,
                                    "ScmType":"Git"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
               "parameters": {
                 "siteName": {
                   "value":"trouble1appservice"
               },
                 "repoUrl": {
                "value":"https://trouble1fake:8f0276be40aaed284ac8862d198fb1e1a17f727f@github.com/trouble1fake/uploadfile"
             },
        "sku": {
              "value": "B1"
            },
            "workerSize": {
              "value": "0"
            },
            "branch": {
              "value": "master"
            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

repoUrl I am using is https://trouble1fake:8f0276be40aaed284ac8862d198fb1e1a17f727f@github.com/trouble1fake/uploadfile

Still its not working.
Or is there any way I can execute commands or import files using rest api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is not how it works.** You have to create artifacts of your GitHub solution first and then deploy it (be it local or pipelines). Pls refer to below approaches and choose the one you desire:

1. You can use `Visual Studio` to deploy your App, once it is cloned in your local from your private repository: **[Deploy an ASP.NET Web App in Azure App Service](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vsts/appservice/)**
2. You can deploy your app using Azure DevOps pipelines, wherein you can add your code in the ADO server and follow the step-by-step process to deploy the app: **[Deploying into Azure App Service using Azure DevOps CI/CD Pipeline](https://devops.com/deploying-into-azure-app-service-using-azure-devops-ci-cd-pipeline/#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20Pipelines%20%2D%3E%20Releases%20%2D,as%20Latest%2C%20click%20on%20Add)**.